# How to check the 302 redirect domain history?

Tags: redirect, dns, hosting

I was buying a domain and I need to verify the history of the domain in-terms of 302 redirects on the domains. is there any way by which I can check a domains history

Answer (score 0):

There are tools and sites available through which you can check their NS records which can be used before for redirection rules as per their name servers also some paid tools are available to get the entire domain history

```
Check whoisrequest.com and go to domain history.
Check archive.org if you would like to check what type of site it was
Check research.domaintools.com/research/hosting-history/ to get entire data
```

hope it helps!